# Qt 5.1.0 on Windows using minGW 4.8 taking a really long time to debug

Tags: c++, windows, qt, debugging, mingw

I have downloaded and installed the Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8) from the qt-project downloads page. I have run the installer, and am able to compile and run applications using these libraries and the minGW 4.8 32-bit toolhchain.

However, I have a large application, and when I try to debug it (using the gdb bundled with the minGW toolchain), it takes an insane amount of time to start running, and any interaction with the application takes a long time to complete. Not an annoying amount of time, but an unusable amount of time. Has anyone else had this problem and are there any solutions?

In case this helps, I get lots of output when debugging like this:

```
Temporarily disabling breakpoints for unloaded shared library "C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\5.1.0\mingw48_32\plugins\somefolder\somelib.dll"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gdb bug that was introduced at some point between 7.4 and 7.5, which makes it much slower. When debugging QObject classes, the slower becomes awfully slow.

By disabling debugging helper, you improve it, but then you miss a lot of precious information in the Local Variables and Expressions. For instance, you cannot display nicely the contents of QLists, etc...

It seems that either:

- buidling gdb from the CVS or
- using an older gdb (7.4.1)

solves the issue.

Answer (score 4):

Qt creator has "attempt quick start" in its gdb options. It helps a LOT.

Or you can switch to using MSVC compiler on Windows. That also switches your debugging to CDB instead of GDB and bypasses the problem entirely. You can just install MSVC compiler and plug it into QtCreator instead of mingw if you don't like MS IDE.

P.S. This also gives you readable core dumps which is a godsend.

Comment: Brought debug launch time from 90sec to 7sec for me. Wonder if the lunch comes for free.

Comment: The lunch does not come for free. Turns out all this option does is postpone library loading until app crash. So when the app crashes and you want to find out why, you still need to wait the extra 83sec. So the benefit from this option is marginal.

Comment: I definitely remember this helping a lot. Certainly nowhere near 80 seconds after this option enabled. Though I have since started using MSVC compiler and this doesnt have that problem. And Unix never had any GDB startup problems to begin with. BTW, msvc compiler comes with an ability to dissect core dumps on windows so you might want to switch too.

Comment: So when you build with a different compiler (MSVC) but keep using the same debugger (gdb), the debugger starts up quickly? That sounds great.

Comment: No, building with MSVC you simply use a different debugger (CDB)

Comment: Ah, and I guess this requires using the VS IDE as well, dropping Qt Creator?

Comment: No it doesn't. You can install free version of MS ide and plug its compiler into qt creator

Comment: Great, that worked. Thanks! I posted [a community wiki answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39254045/122687) that repeats what you said, so such useful knowledge doesn't stay buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments on [Zeks' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21146288/122687). There he explains that switching from the MinGW toolchain to the Microsoft toolchain (compiler, debugger) solves the problem completely. Fortunately, Qt Creator supports the Microsoft toolchain so you don't need to switch IDEs.

After I did that, debugger launch time is now 4sec, and on app crash it there is zero delay. It also [sped up builds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39253440/122687) a lot.

For reference, I've described how I've set up my system [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39253440/122687).

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to improve the debugging speed significantly after changing several settings:

- Made sure the compiler is gcc.exe and not g++.exe in the `Qt5.1.0\Tools\mingw48_32\bin` folder
- Unchecked `Use Debugging Helper` in the Tools->Options->Debugger->Locals & Expressions menu
- Unchecked `Stop when qWarning() is called` and `Stop when qFatal() is called`

Comment: There's no difference between gcc and g++. It's still the same compiler. The first item on your list is a no-op.

Comment: For sure debugging helper improves speed, but that's a major feature and watching at Qt classes while debugging is nearly impossible without it.