# Qt Creator build with the MinGW toolchain is slowish

Tags: mingw, qt-creator

When building in Qt Creator using the MinGW toolchain, on Windows, the build is slowish. Takes 21sec for a tiny project.

Any fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to switch to the Microsoft toolchain (including the MSVC compiler and the CDB debugger). Qt Creator supports that toolchain. This brought down build time for me from 21 to 11sec.

Also, it brought "build when nothing has changed from the last build" from 4 to 0sec which is a big win as well.

Note: The "Compilers" tab in Qt Creator's options listed a big bunch of MSVC compilers, including:

- Compilers from the Windows SDK, for 3 different architectures
- "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 10.0" for 2 different architectures
- "Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0" for 3 different architectures

The one I selected is **"Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler 14.0 (x86)"**

Disclaimer: performance may be different on other systems. I'm running a 32bit Windows 7 system.